# Não consigo acessar item de array dentro de objeto

Tags: javascript, node.js

Estou aprendendo orientação á objetos em JavaScript utilizando NodeJS, e num código de aprendizado criei duas classes: Pessoa e Agenda, na qual a Agenda tem um array da classe Pessoa, e numa função de buscar pessoa por nome que implementei eu não consigo obter o resultado da função.

Classes que criei:

```js
class Pessoa {
    constructor(nome, telefone) {
        this.nome = nome
        this.telefone = telefone
    }
}

class Agenda {
    constructor(_options) {
        this.pessoas = []

        if (_options.length)
            this.length = _options.length
        else
            this.length = 10
    }

    length() {
        return this.length
    }

    adicionarPessoa(Pessoa) {
        this.pessoas.push(Pessoa)
    }

    buscaPessoa(index) {
        return this.pessoas[index]
    }

    buscaPessoaPorNome(nome) {
        this.pessoas.forEach(async (pessoa, index)=>{
            if (pessoa.nome === nome) {
                return pessoa
            }
        })
    }

    listaPessoas() {
        this.pessoas.forEach((pessoa, index)=>{
            console.log(`ID: ${index}\n Nome: ${pessoa.nome}\n Telefone: ${pessoa.telefone}`)
        })
    }
}
```

Código onde instancio e adiciono 2 pessoas á agenda e tento acessar uma por nome:

```js
var agenda = new Agenda({length: 10})

agenda.adicionarPessoa(new Pessoa('Bruno', '87 9 8000-5000'))

agenda.adicionarPessoa(new Pessoa('Luis', '87 9 1324-8962'))

var pessoa = agenda.buscaPessoaPorNome('Bruno')

console.log(pessoa.nome) //undefined <<---
```

Consegui resolver utilizando `pessoas.find()` do array.

```js
buscaPessoaPorNome(nome) {
        /* this.pessoas.forEach(async (pessoa, index)=>{
            if (pessoa.nome === nome) {
                return pessoa
            }
        }) */
        return this.pessoas.find(e=>e.nome===nome)
}
```

Comment: Por que não usa o método  [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) para localização? `return this.pessoas.find(e=>e===nome);`

Comment: Não sei se ajudaria pois cada pessoa é um objeto, e preciso comparar a propriedade `nome` dele. Vou alterar a pergunta agora.

Comment: Você testou? `buscaPessoaPorNome(nome) {return this.pessoas.find(e=>e===nome);}`

Comment: Acabei de testar da maneira correta e consegui! Havia esquecido de por o `return`. Obrigado!

Comment: Eu não sei fechar a pergunta ainda. Estou tentando descobrir.

Comment: Você pode a remover ou então a responder como qualquer usuário ou a deixar aberta para que alguém a responda.

Comment: Responde você, @AugustoVasques!! Se tiver tempo pra isso, claro. :D

Comment: @LuizFelipe quem sabe mais tarde.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilizei o retorno do método `pessoas.find(e=>e.nome===nome)` e consegui obter o resultado que desejava.

```js
...
buscaPessoaPorNome(nome) {        
        return this.pessoas.find(e=>e.nome===nome);
}
...

const agenda = new Agenda({length: 10});

agenda.adicionarPessoa(new Pessoa('Bruno', '87 9 8161-5939'));

agenda.adicionarPessoa(new Pessoa('Luis', '87 9 1324-8962'));

console.log(buscaPessoaPorNome('Bruno')); //Pessoa { nome: 'Bruno', telefone: '87 9 8161-5939' }
```